# Opening a bank account with cash: How should bills be presented?

Tags: bank-account, deposits, paper-money

I am opening a checking account tomorrow and am planning to deposit $700 that I have in cash to start. It is made up of 30 twenty dollar bills and one one hundred dollar bill. How should I organize it to be the least hassle for the person handling it. I currently have the twenties in 6 rolls of 5, and the one hundred is just by itself. Is there a specific way that you are supposed to group it? Should I label them? Or is what I did fine? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I’m just a little anxious about it, and wanted to be sure.

Comment: Not a stupid question! You might be overthinking it, however.

Comment: The bank won't care.  The teller will just sort and count the bills anyway.

Comment: ... i.e. use their counting machine. It will help if the bills are reasonably flat (so do not fold each single bill individually)

Comment: 31 bills is not that many bills. Not for a bank.

Answer (score 4):

> I currently have the twenties in 6 rolls of 5

I don't know what "roll" means to you (perhaps it's another word for grouping).  I think of it as money rolled into a circular shape.  Do not do that.  Place all the money flat and together.  Possibly hand them the hundred and twenties separately if you want to emphasize that.

An [envelope](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/86848/25282) with the amount on it is a good idea.  Flat, not folded, not rolled, not separated by paperclips or rubber bands.  A [simple pile](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/86706/25282) of money is best.  Folding the money once to put in your pocket is fine but unfold it to hand it to the teller.

The reason for flat money is that it will most easily go through the money counters.  Rolling makes the money curved and increases the chance of a jam.

And I apologize if that was just a turn of phrase.  But I can easily envision some poor teller sighing with exasperation on being handed rolled money that then needs to be flattened to go through the machine.  Particularly if the person handing it over grouped it that way in an attempt to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, banks, businesses and the government stack cash.  That's how you should present it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Banks have electronic money counters so the order really doesn't matter. When I make a cash deposit that's large, I usually just put it in an envelope and hand it over.

Comment: Some banks may have electonic counters, but not all.  Even those that do might not bother for a small amount like the OP is depositing.